# Regex for replacing quotes in a string doesnot work in clojure

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

Am trying to replace the quotes in my string like so with an empty value:

```
(clojure.string/replace "Invalid password." #"\" " " ")
```

this, however, does not remove the quotes.

When I try:

```
(clojure.string/replace "Invalid password." #"\. " "testing")
```

this works

what could be the problem?

Comment: Your input string doesn't contain any quotes. What is the output you get and what do are you expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only, as in the comment mentioned, doesn't

```clj
"Invalid password."
```

contain a quote `"\""`. Furthermore, your regex has a space in it. But when you remove the space in the regex (`#"\""` instead of `#"\" "`), and take `"Invalid \"password\"."` as argument, it works as you wanted:

```clj
(clojure.string/replace "Invalid \"password\"." #"\"" " ")
```

yields

```clj
"Invalid  password ."
```